# Retrieve first non-NA value from a group of columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm a pretty new coder so if you guys could help me that'd be great.

Let's say I have one dataframe:
[image]

Can I combine "Number" and "Number 2" in a way where "Number" takes precedence unless there is no value(NaN). When "Number" is NaN, then we use the entry in "Number 2"

It should look like this [image]

In other words, I want to combine "Number" and "Number 2" where if "Number" is NaN, then use "Number 2"'s entry. If "Number" has an entry, keep it for the merged entry. This is similar to left merge for merging two data frames.

Btw, I'm using python and pandas.

Update: trying to use np.where

[image]

Output without np.where:  [image]

Output with np.where: [image]

Comment: Please provide a small set of sample data in the form of text that we can copy and paste. Include the corresponding desired result. Check out the guide on [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/3620003).

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `apply`:

```
df['Number'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Number'] if not pd.isnull(row['Number']) else row['Number2'], axis=1)
```

Just need to `drop` the Number2 column then

Comment: This also only works for two columns and is excrusiatingly slow on larger data. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code for more. cc @user3085496

Comment: @cs95 I wasn't aware of this - thank you for sharing!!

Answer (score 1):

#### `bfill(axis=1)` and `iloc`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': df['Name'],
    'Number': df.filter(like='Number').bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]
})
```